Is there any information about the archive node parameter configuration of peple-polkadot?
I haven't seen any information about this on GitHub or Polkadot official documentation.
It would be great if someone could help.

Not sure what you mean.
The polkadot-parachain binary released as part of Polkadot-SDK (e.g. polkadot-parachain stable2407-2), is able to run collator nodes for all system chains (including people-polkadot). There should be no special arguments for people-polkadot nodes.
